# Can I put a 27 × 1 3/8 tyre on a 700×28c wheel?

Tags: tire, wheels, compatibility, rims, 27-inch

I want to use a 37×630 tyre on a 700×28c (28-622) rim. Will they fit and be safe to ride?

Comment: I was going to flag this as a duplicate, but the answer(s) I found were imbedded in a much more overarching question.  This question is simple and to the point (and the answer is NO, you cannot put a 27-inch tire on a 700C (28-622) rim and safely ride it).  A direct answer to this question would be helpful, so I am electing to keep it (editing it first).  There are questions on the reverse (700C tire on 27-inch rim), but none that simply address the 27 on 700C question.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The 630mm rim (that's where the 630 comes from) has 8mm larger diameter than 622mm rim. If you put the 630mm tire on 622mm rim on one side, there will be a 8 mm gap on the other side. It will not stay in place, and but you somehow manage to install a tube and inflate it without dislocating the tire, the tube will bulge between rim and tire everywhere. I'd be actually interested to see if someone could pull that off.